How to copy node_js directory from 1 server(Linux) to another server(Linux) in jenkins scripted pipeline?
when I copy whole directory from one server to another server I use this below script
stage('deploy to another server'){
            steps{
                sshagent(['SSHAgent']) {
                 sh 'scp -r StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_js/* ec2-user@54.83.76.126:/home/ec2-user'
                }
            }
        }

but it showing this error
+ scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_js/node_modules /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_js/package-lock.json /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_js/package.json /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_js/server.js ec2-user@54.83.76.126:/home/ec2-user
  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_js/node_modules is not a regular file
  failed to upload file /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/node_js/node_modules to /home/ec2-user/n\`ode_modules

node_modules is a directory which is into the node_js directory
What is be the right syntax to copy whole directory from one to another server?

The error shown doesn't have -r argument are you sure the error is from this satge?

like @MedAgou suggested error and the command doesn't match up. If we only look at the error then -r flag is missing. try the command with -r -o flags.
